# Cannot load any MSBuild project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I've just started learning MSBuild and tried to load the below simple test project to Visual Studio 2013 (Update 5), but I'm getting the error 'The project system has encountered an error' - 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'

Note I can successfully build the project with MSBuild from command line, just want to see it in VS project tree as part of a solution among the other csproj/vcxproj/etc. projects.

I've tried several ways, changing bits and pieces in msbuildproj file, etc.  - no success, always getting the same error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Are MSBuild projects not supposed to be added to VS solution?

```
<!-- mytest.msbuildproj -->
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" >
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="Building my target" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

[The project system has encountered an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSf8U.png)

VsProjectFault_8c79b7c1-086a-47e9-be8c-46300a431de3.failure.txt:

> =====================
>   01/03/2016 17:10:25
>   Recoverable
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>      at Microsoft.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.PhysicalProjectTreeProvider.GetProjectRootProperties(ConfiguredProjectExports configuredProjectExports)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.PhysicalProjectTreeProvider.GenerateOriginalTree(ConfiguredProjectExports configuredProjectExports, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.PhysicalProjectTreeProvider.<GenerateOriginalTreeAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.Designers.ProjectTreeProviderBase.<>c__DisplayClass9.<<Initialize>b__5>d__b.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass5.<SubmitErrorReport>b__3()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Guard>b__0()
>      at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>      at Microsoft.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.PhysicalProjectTreeProvider.GetProjectRootProperties(ConfiguredProjectExports configuredProjectExports)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.PhysicalProjectTreeProvider.GenerateOriginalTree(ConfiguredProjectExports configuredProjectExports, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.PhysicalProjectTreeProvider.<GenerateOriginalTreeAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.Designers.ProjectTreeProviderBase.<>c__DisplayClass9.<<Initialize>b__5>d__b.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass5.<SubmitErrorReport>b__3()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Guard>b__0()
>      at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )<---

===================

Comment: A project file is important to MSBuild, tells it what to do.  It is however *also* important to the IDE, tells it what it should display in the Solution Explorer window.  Those two functions don't overlap much.  Basic problem with this one is that there is *nothing* useful that the IDE can do with it.  You ought to start from one that the IDE creates and work your way backwards, perhaps.

Comment: Or simply like this, Visual Studio assumes the script file to contain a series of tags, which this file fails to present. So though it is a valid MSBuild script, it is not a valid VS project file.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. And any idea how I can find out which tags are missing? I cannot create MSBuild type project from VS IDE.

Comment: You could start from a makefile project, which is relatively small, and have it execute whatever msbuild code you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all msbuild files are created equal. Sure you can craft one from scratch, and run it on the command line. But that doesn't mean visual studio will like that file.

Visual studio needs a msbuild file with a certain schema, and the above file doesn't fit the bill.

Comment: Sadly it is not trivial how to make MSBuild project compatible with the IDE, hence answer accepted.

Comment: I would suggest therefore to use property sheets as much as possible. Then take an msbuild file that VS generates and whittle it down line by line until you get to the bare bones.